# Columns as backgrounds will not expand to match page height

Tags: html, css

I am using two divs to create the look of a two-tone background. behind my container div, the left side is blue and the right side is yellow. My css for these column divs is:

```
#bluecol{
height:100%;
background-color: #5C8AE6;
display: inline;
float: none;
left: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 50%;
z-index: -5;}
```

and for the yellowcol is the same, except positioned to the right, naturally. Currently both divs works fine but I cannot get them to match the height of the content within my container, I can only set the height manually or to 100%, which only takes up the browser's window. My container is set to height:max-content so is unhelpful in this situation.

I want the two column divs to match whatever the containers height is. Any suggestions would be great!

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ak0kp9xd/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ak0kp9xd/3/)**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#bluecol {
    height:100%;
    background-color: #5C8AE6;
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    left: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: -5;
}
#yellowcol {
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 204, 0);
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    right:0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: -5;
}
#container {
    background-color:#E5ECFB;
    font-family:'calibri';
    margin:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:5;
    font-size:medium;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your background blocks must be inside `#container` to take it's height.

Also you can use `:before` to reduce HTML markup:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(255, 204, 0);
  padding: 10px;
}
#container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #5C8AE6;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
#container .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #E5ECFB;
  border-right: 11px solid #FFE994;
  border-left: 11px solid #AFC6F3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">Whatever</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is great code but I'm afraid the height:100% still doesn't work for me :(. Even with .content within my container.